# VB Script - Undefined variable

Tags: vbscript

I'm getting 'variable is undefined', I'm guessing this has something to do with the scope of variables in vbscript, but my knowledge is limited with this.

I know the loading of the email addresses works and the actual emailing because I have checked these separately.  I'm trying to loop through a list of email addresses and send the log file to each..

Any additional information would be great!

First, there is a var array at the top of the file:

```
dim emails()

function getEmailAddresses()

    dim objFSO
    dim objConfigFile
    dim strLine
    dim iCounter

    const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8  

    set objFSO = createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    set objConfigFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("emailAddresses.config", ForReading)

    iCounter = 0

    do while not objConfigFile.AtEndOfStream
        redim preserve emails(iCounter)
        strLine = trim(objConfigFile.ReadLine)
        emails(iCounter) = strLine
        iCounter = iCounter + 1
    loop

    objConfigFile.Close

end function

function writetolog(strLogtext) 
    dim objFSO
    dim objLogfile

    const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8

    set objFSO = createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    set objLogfile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("xxx.log", ForAppending, true) 
    objLogfile.Writeline now() & "  -  " & strLogText   
    objLogfile.Close 

    call EmailLogFile(strLogText)

end function


function EmailLogFile(bodyText)

    for each emailAddress in emails

        set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
        objEmail.From = "File.Mover@xxxxxxx.xxx"

        objEmail.To = emailAddress
        objEmail.Subject = "File Move Log" 
        objEmail.Textbody = bodyText
        objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
            ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
        objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
            ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = _
        "xxxxxx" 
        objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
            ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
        objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Update
        objEmail.Send

   next
end function
```

Comment: You forgot to put the `Option Explicit` declaration at the top of your code. **Always**, always write VBScript with `Option Explicit` turned on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're calling `getEmailAddresses()` anywhere so your file won't be read and your `emails` array won't be populated

Answer (score 0):

What line is the undefined var at? Or what is the var name?

Either way, 'strLogText' is not defined anywhere.  Also, if this is a classic ASP page put an Option Explicit statement at the top.

Comment: Oh yeah, the undefined variable is inside the loop for the email addresses 'emailAddresses'

Comment: Just put 'Dim emailAddresses' above the loop line, does that fix it?

Comment: Afraid not, but that's the loop variable so it suspect it wouldn't?

Comment: It is not emailAddressess but emailAddress and it is not declared. Also objEmail needs to be declared. strLogText however is declared in the fuction definition.